# Make Web API IModelBinder apply to all instances of the type

Tags: c#, model-binding, asp.net-web-api2, imodelbinder

I'm using a custom IModelBinder to try to convert strings into NodaTime LocalDates.  My `LocalDateBinder` looks like this:

```
public class LocalDateBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private readonly LocalDatePattern _localDatePattern = LocalDatePattern.IsoPattern;

    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext.ModelType != typeof(LocalDate))
            return false;

        var val = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (val == null)
            return false;

        var rawValue = val.RawValue as string;

        var result = _localDatePattern.Parse(rawValue);
        if (result.Success)
            bindingContext.Model = result.Value;

        return result.Success;
    }
}
```

In my WebApiConfig I register this modelbinder using `SimpleModelBinderProvider`, a la

```
var provider = new SimpleModelBinderProvider(typeof(LocalDate), new LocalDateBinder());
config.Services.Insert(typeof(ModelBinderProvider), 0, provider);
```

This works great when I have an action that takes a parameter of type LocalDate, but if I have a more complex action that uses a LocalDate inside another model, it never gets fired.  For example:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("validateDates")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ValidateDates(string userName, [FromUri] LocalDate beginDate, [FromUri] LocalDate endDate)
{
     //works fine
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Create(CreateRequest createRequest)
{
     //doesn't bind LocalDate properties inside createRequest (other properties are bound correctly)
     //i.e., createRequest.StartDate isn't bound
}
```

I figure this has something to do with how I'm registering the model binder with Web API, but I'm at a loss as to what I need to correct - do I need a custom binder provider?

Comment: For anyone looking at this, I never got this solved.  The real problem though was that my JSON serialization settings were getting the way of deserializing NodaTime objects - I needed to override the default DateTime handlers.

Answer (score 3):

Your `CreateRequest` is a complex type which doesn't have a type converter of model binder defined. In this case, Web Api will try to use a media-type formatter. As you are using JSON, it will try to use the default JSON formatter, which is Newtonsoft Json.Net in a standard configuration. Json.Net doesn't know how to handle Noda Time types out of the box.

To make Json.Net able to handle Noda Time types, you should install [NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet/) and add something like this to your startup code...

```
public void Config(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);
    app.UseWebApi(config);
}
```

After this, your second example will then work as expected, and `ModelState.IsValid` will be `false` if the input was not in the correct format Noda Time.

See http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api for more information on parameter binding in Web API.